# Unknowingly ask an already asked question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225805/java-typecasting-confusion) yesterday on SO, as I was not able to get an answer using Google, and some time later a member posted a thread reference which had an answer to my question.

That thread contains question similar to mine with better answers, which brings me to **my question** that, if I cannot find my answer Googling or using the search facility of SO and post a question to ask it, only to realise later that it has already been asked and had a better-quality answer, what should I do with my question (*shall I delete it or add the reference by myself to that question for future visitors*)?

*A mean sidenote:* That question gave me 3 upvotes, so I was little hesitant to delete it too! :)

Comment: You can't delete it. It has upvoted answers. So just vote to close it as a duplicate of the one that was found.

Comment: hmmm...ok...did that already!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - The community will help you with that now :) Already 3 close votes..

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ : thats the thing with Community...4 votes now..damn, people are eager to close down things!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor I hope that this wasn't a plea to downvote the question, though :)

Comment: @devnull : **certainly not** , i just felt bad on repetition of efforts...... **please dont downvote, i dont have rep like u people** :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the question be.

Duplicates make it easier to search for questions as they offer a different way of asking the same question. Searching with your search terms didn't get you to the original question, now the same terms do get you there. It's still likely to help others, but do vote to close it as duplicate.